# zxing-cpp generate image with cleartext

Tags: c++, rendering, barcode, zxing

Subject actually gives all info; to slightly elaborate:

I need to print barcodes (ITF format, if it matters) and I can easily do it with the demo
application:

```
ZXingWriter -size 300x50 -margin 10 ITF "99229997243313" test.jpg
```

Now I would line to add clear-text to the image, something like:

[image: this barcode]

Notice digits are vertically aligned with bars coding them, so it's not "just print text on the image".

Is it possible and, if so, how?
I did a (not too extensive) search, but I didn't find anything relevant.

Note: I am using the standard example for testing but I will have to
incorporate whatever solution (possibly a "non aligned fallback")
in my own C++ program so any code I can include is perfectly right,
I do *not* need to do it with plain `ZXingWriter`